# how can I make R recognise the dates successfully in my view while exporting data from oracle sql db

Tags: sql, r, oracle, date, view

Trying to export a view created in oracle sql developer to R **using RODBC** The view includes many date fields.

All other date fileds are being exported to R successfully except for below two:

- PAYOR_BIRTH_DATE
- INSURED_BIRTH_DATE

Initially, related lines were simply as below (as they are stored as date in the database) in the source code of my view:

```
SELECT

PAYOR_BIRTH_DATE,

INSURED_BIRTH_DATE

FROM

MY_TABLE
```

After getting an error message as "*Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format*" , secondly, I have tried below:

```
to_char(PAYOR_BIRTH_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')

to_char(INSURED_BIRTH_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

then I could get these fields to R successfully. However R recognised them as character instead of date.

Thirdly, I have tried my chance as below to help R recognise them as date; but it didn't worked. **(R recognised them as characted again.)**

to_date(to_char(PAYOR_BIRTH_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')

to_date(to_char(INSURED_BIRTH_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')

Note: I have noticed that these two fields include both nulls and dates as "1900-01-01". I know that nulls are not problem for R while recognising them as date. But I am not sure if the values "1900-01-01" have any effect on this..

My question is how can I make R recognise them as date automatically during the export?

**Sample data for these two date fields are below. My NLS settings as "YYYY-MM-DD".**

```
PAYOR_BIRTH_DATE

1900-01-01

1900-01-01

1926-01-01

1927-02-21

1927-03-11


INSURED_BIRTH_DATE

1900-01-01

1900-01-01

1900-01-01

1926-03-01

1926-10-11
```

**R code:**

```
library(RODBC)

my_dataframe <- sqlQuery(my_connection,"SELECT * FROM MY_VIEW", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Screenshot of the field types in original table used in the view.**

"DOGTAR" is the original name, one of these two fields in the source table used in my view.

[image]

Comment: Please post sample data of the Oracle dates so we can reproduce. Also *but it didn't worked* is not specific on result of third attempt. Any errors? Undesired results? Finally what db API package are you using: RODBC? ROracle? Might as well post library lines and R code with sql.

Comment: @Parfait, please see my edits in bold, regarding to your comments.

Comment: @Parfait, I have hust formatted them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have Oracle but using RODBC on another database, posted dates render perfectly as `POSIXct`. In your view, are these fields actually datetimes or string? Better question: do these fields derive from datetime fields of source tables or do you manipulate with string functions? Maybe post the SQL of the view?

Comment: I have rechecked the sources of these fields; originally they are both stored as date. It seems they are stored as data but actually I do not know how they are stored in real; how ca I see this? Please see the latest edit at the end, showing the type of the fields in the source table                                                                           .                            For the SQL of my view, I do not make any manipulation for these fields; I directly add them to select part from source the table.

Comment: You are probably better off with exporting the dates as character in `"YYYY-MM-DD"` format and then converting the resp. columns of the read-in `data.frame` to date in a second step. You could try the `dmy` function of package `lubridate`.